# How do I convert a string to timestamp format in Data Refinery from Watson Studio?

Tags: watson-studio, watson-knowledge-catalog, ibm-data-refinery

I have a csv file that has a timestamp column but it shows up as a String type since I uploaded it locally to the project in Watson Studio. Can Data Refinery convert that string column into actual Timestamp type format?

Comment: It might be helpful to include the timestamp format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Convert Type operation and select the format of timestamp that matches your data. It's not limited to a specific timestamp format...there are different formats you can choose from.  For example:

[image]